# convert non-scientific values in a list to scientific values using TCL

Tags: list, floating-point, tcl, scientific-notation

I have a list of values contain both scientific and floating numbers,need to convert the non scientific values to scientific values for list operations.

```
set Y_value [list 1.215647671415354e-7 1.1284486163276597e-6 4.538622670224868e-5 4.4706815970130265e-5 8.492852430208586e-6 6.077577836549608e-6 3.1041158763400745e-6
0.00015045881445985287 4.1016753016265284e-7 1.165599314845167e-6 1.8736355968940188e-6 2.9444883693940938e-5 2.5420340534765273e-5 2.0819682049477706e-6 9.529731869406532e-6
8.549810104341304e-7 1.558014082547743e-5 8.079621693468653e-6 4.868444739258848e-5 0.0001646481396164745]
```

This is the current list, I want to convert the floating values of the list to scientific values, and store them in new list using TCL.

Expected output

```
1.2156476714e-04 1.1284486163e-03 4.5386226702e-02 4.4706815970e-02 8.4928524302e-03 6.0775778365e-03 
3.1041158763e-03 1.5045881446e-01 4.1016753016e-04 1.1655993148e-03 1.8736355969e-03 2.9444883694e-02
2.5420340535e-02 2.0819682049e-03 9.5297318694e-03 8.5498101043e-04 1.5580140825e-02 8.0796216935e-03
4.8684447393e-02 1.6464813962e-01
```

Comment: Look at http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: your example output values are 1000x those of your input values.  For example, input `1.215647671415354e-7` becomes output `1.2156476714e-04`.  I've added this in the code as `factor`.

You can use `tcl`'s `format` command to do this, as follows:

```
set Y_value [list 1.215647671415354e-7 1.1284486163276597e-6 4.538622670224868e-5 4.4706815970130265e-5 8.492852430208586e-6 6.077577836549608e-6 3.1041158763400745e-6 \
0.00015045881445985287 4.1016753016265284e-7 1.165599314845167e-6 1.8736355968940188e-6 2.9444883693940938e-5 2.5420340534765273e-5 2.0819682049477706e-6 9.529731869406532e-6 \
8.549810104341304e-7 1.558014082547743e-5 8.079621693468653e-6 4.868444739258848e-5 0.0001646481396164745]

set factor 1000
set Y_value_scientific [list]
foreach v $Y_value {
    lappend Y_value_scientific [format %1.10e [expr {$v*$factor}]]
}

puts $Y_value_scientific
```

---

Note: if you are using Tcl 8.6 or newer, I recommend the one-liner answer by @Shawn using `lmap`.

Answer (score 3):

For creating a new list based on an existing one, [`lmap`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lmap.htm) is the way to go.

Something like:

```
set result [lmap y $Y_value { format %.10e [expr {$y * 1000}] }]
```

Comment: Just a note: `lmap` is great, but you need Tcl `8.6`.

Comment: @rtx13 I feel bad for anyone who isn't using 8.6, considering how long it's been around.